# Firefox 4 + Ubuntu 10.04 + Google page

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, firefox

I don't understand what's happening with Google.pt in Firefox.

Here is a screenshot of the page.

[image]

*Click for a larger version*

The characters are all messed up and it's only on Google.pt, every other site works as usual.

I have recently installed Firefox 4 on Ubuntu 10.04.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the menu Tools/Options/Content/Languages Choose.
Check if you have any unwanted language that has higher priority than Portuguese.

You could also try uninstalling and reinstalling Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

The Operating System is probably matching what it considers to be the closest font to what Google is specifying.  That page seems to include the following fonts in its compound stylesheet (according to Opera):

- "arial", sans-serif

If you don't have either of these fonts on your system, then installing one of them may resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to google.us so you can see what everything says.

click on language tools, go down to where it says use google interface in your language, and click the preferences link to set up your localization.

Answer (score 0):

Check your "interface language" setting for Google search. If you are signed in, you can do this at [Google Preferences](http://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en). Make sure it's set to the language you want to use.

[image]

Be sure to click the "Save Preferences" button in the blue section on the right at the top of the page when you're done.